# How to parse invalid JSON contianing invalid number

Tags: json, python-3.x

I work with a legacy customer who sends me webhook events. Sometimes their system sends me a   value that looks like this

```json
[{"id":"LXKhRA3RHtaVBhnczVRJLdr","ecc":"0X6","cph":"X1X4X77074", "ts":16XX445656000}]
```

I am using python's `json.loads` to parse the data sent to me. Here the `ts` is an invalid number and **python** gives `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` whenever I try to parse this string.

It is okay with me to get `None` in `ts` field if I can not parse it.

What would be a smart (& possibly generic) way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be so *generic*, but you can try using `yaml` to load:

```
import yaml

s = '[{"id":"LXKhRA3RHtaVBhnczVRJLdr","ecc":"0X6","cph":"X1X4X77074","ts":16XX445656000}]'
yaml.safe_load(s)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 'LXKhRA3RHtaVBhnczVRJLdr',
  'ecc': '0X6',
  'cph': 'X1X4X77074',
  'ts': '16XX445656000'}]
```

Comment: This, or, if the payload is always the same structure, some simple string processing before `json.loads()`.

Comment: This is helpful - thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is always in the `ts` key, and this value is always a string of numbers and letters, you could just remove it before trying to parse:

```
import re

jstr = """[{"id":"LXKhRA3RHtaVBhnczVRJLdr","ecc":"0X6","cph":"X1X4X77074", "ts":16XX445656000}]"""

jstr_sanitized = re.sub(r',?\s*\"ts\":[A-Z0-9]+', "", jstr)
jobj = json.loads(jstr_sanitized)

# [{'id': 'LXKhRA3RHtaVBhnczVRJLdr', 'ecc': '0X6', 'cph': 'X1X4X77074'}]
```

Regex explanation ([try online](https://regex101.com/r/cnHAlc/1)):

```
,?\s*\"ts\":[A-Z0-9]+

,?                      Zero or one commas
  \s*                   Any number of whitespace characters
     \"ts\":            Literally "ts":
            [A-Z0-9]+   One or more uppercase letters or numbers
```

---

Alternatively, you could catch the `JSONDecodeError` and look at its `pos` attribute for the offending character. Then, you could either remove just that character and try again, or look for the next space, comma, or bracket and remove characters until that point before you try again.

```
jstr = """[{"id":"LXKhRA3RHtaVBhnczVRJLdr","ecc":"0X6","cph":"X1X4X77074", "ts":16XX445656000}]"""
while True:
    try:
        jobj = json.loads(jstr)
        break
    except json.JSONDecodeError as ex:
        jstr = jstr[:ex.pos] + jstr[ex.pos+1:]
```

This mangles the output so that the `ts` key is now a valid integer (after removing the `X`s) but since you don't care about that anyway, it should be fine:

```
[{'id': 'LXKhRA3RHtaVBhnczVRJLdr',
  'ecc': '0X6',
  'cph': 'X1X4X77074',
  'ts': 16445656000}]
```

Since you'd end up repeatedly re-parsing the initial valid part, this is probably not a great idea if you have a huge json string, or there are lots of places that could throw an error, but it should be fine for the kind of example you have shown.

Comment: I had some regex in mind too - but the accepted answer solved it for me - thanks for your reply